# Matplotlib Error when trying to display seaborn heat maps side by side

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I'm using a for loop to plot 4 confusion matrices side by side:

```
palette = ['Blues', 'Reds', 'Greens', 'Oranges']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,4)
for ax in axs: 
    
for i in range(0,4):
    axs[i]=contingency_table(data['outputs'][i], predictions[i].round(), color_map = palette[I])
```

Running this plots something really weird but doesn't return any error:
[image]

The function I'm calling is defined:

```
def contingency_table(y_true, y_pred, color_map):
    
    #create the confusion matrix
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    
    
    
    group_names = ['True Negative','Type II Error','Type I Error','True Positive']
    group_counts = ['{0:0.0f}'.format(value) for value in
                cnf_matrix.flatten()]
    group_percentages = ['{0:.2%}'.format(value) for value in
                     cnf_matrix.flatten()/np.sum(cnf_matrix)]
    labels = [f'{v1}\n{v2}\n{v3}' for v1, v2, v3 in zip(group_names,group_counts,group_percentages)]
    labels = np.asarray(labels).reshape(2,2)
    
    return sns.heatmap(cnf_matrix, annot=labels, fmt='', cmap= color_map,);
```

And I intended on using it in the following way:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6));
contingency_table(y1_val, pred, color_map = 'Blues');
```

Perhaps I need to change the function or my for loop but I don't know how. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a lot of information, making it hard to point out corrections.

Some misunderstanding is that `axs[i]=contingency_table(...)` would place a plot onto `axs[i]`.  Matplotlib doesn't work like that.  The `ax` needs to be passed as a parameter to `contingency_table(....., ax=ax)` which on its turn can pass it to `sns.heatmap(..., ax=ax)`.

Note that calling `sns.heatmap` without providing an `ax` will use matplotlib's "current ax". In this case, the "current ax" is the last subplot that was created (`axs[3]`). So the post's code draws the 4 heatmaps all on `axs[3]`, creating 4 colorbars.

The outline of the functions would thus look like:

```py
def contingency_table(y_true, y_pred, color_map, ax):
    ...
    sns.heatmap(cnf_matrix, annot=labels, fmt='', cmap=color_map, ax=ax)

...
color_maps = ['Blues', 'Reds', 'Greens', 'Oranges']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4)
for i, (ax, color_map) in enumerate(zip(axs, color_maps)):
    contingency_table(data['outputs'][i], predictions[i].round(), color_map=color_map, ax=ax)
```